# Bower list command without dev builds

Tags: bower

I have bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.7",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.4",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.7",
    "angular-inview": "1.5.4",
    "angular-messages": "1.4.7",
    "angular-mocks": "1.4.7",
    "angular-route": "1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.7",
    "angular-scroll": "0.7.2",
    "angular-touch": "1.4.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "angularytics": "0.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "public/app",
  "private": true
}
```

and when I run `bower list` in my console, I get:

```
...
├── angular#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.0-build.4300+sha.f02811f) 
├─┬ angular-animate#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.0-build.4300+sha.f02811f) 
│ └── angular#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.0-build.4300+sha.f02811f) 
├─┬ angular-bootstrap#0.13.4 
│ └── angular#1.4.7 (1.5.0-build.4300+sha.f02811f available) 
├─┬ angular-cookies#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.0-build.4300+sha.f02811f) 
...
```

However, I'm much more interested in stable versions and I'm not interested in dev builds. Can I fix that somehow? As far as I understand Bower I don't think it is possible but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates):

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

and then running

```
npm-check-updates -m bower
```

(Thanks [Oliver Salzburg](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/259953))